# Trying to understand async/await and Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know a few things about async/ await is that only async functions can use await, await waits for a promise/async-function to return a resolve or reject. I was hence trying to learn it in depth but got confused as why this code wasnt giving expected results

```
var x = [1]

const add2 = async () => {
    x = [...x, 2]
    return Promise.resolve()
}

const add3 = async () =>  {
    setTimeout(() => {
        x = [...x, 3]
        return Promise.resolve()
    }, 4000)
}

const final = async () => {
    console.log(x)
    await add2()
    console.log(x)
    await add3()
    console.log(x)
}

final()
```

This would give me output as

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

Whereas my expected output was

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

So i tried to make a few changes and i got the output

```
var x = [1]

const add2 = async () => {
    x = [...x, 2]
    return Promise.resolve()
}

const add3 = (z) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        x = [...x, 3]
        console.log(z)
        return resolve()
    }, 4000)
})

const final = async () => {
    console.log(x)
    await add2()
    console.log(x)
    await add3()
    console.log(x)
}

final()
```

So i am confusion wether i can implement this functionality using just async function and not defining a new promise

Comment: You do not need to return a resolve(). You can just `resolve()` and not return anything.

Comment: And I would recommend you [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) your elements into your array

Comment: Sometimes you'll *need* to wrap a promise around a callback to be able to use it with async / await. Your function with `setTimeout` is a good example where there is no way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the first snippet is in the `add3` function

```
const add3 = async () =>  {
    setTimeout(() => {
        x = [...x, 3]
        return Promise.resolve()
    }, 4000)
}
```

In the above, `return Promise.resolve()` will be the return statement of the anonymous function passed to `setTimeout` but you're expecting it to be the return of the `add3` async function. So `return Promise.resolve()` is not used anywhere.

```
const add3 = (z) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        x = [...x, 3]
        console.log(z)
        return resolve()
    }, 4000)
})
```

The second snippet works because even though `return resolve()` is the return of the inner arrow function, `resolve` param belongs to the wrapping promise so it resolves the same.